# Weaker version of inverse semigroup

Tags: divisibility, semigroups

Is there a weaker version of inverse semigroup where the existence of reflexive inverse is dropped, only the uniqueness remains.

This was motivated by, and resembles the weaker version of divisible: cancellable -- the former requires both existence and uniqueness, while the latter only requires uniqueness.

More formally, a "weakly inverse semigroup" is a semigroup $S$ such that $\forall a, p, q \in S\ (apa=a \wedge pap=p \wedge aqa=a \wedge qaq=q \rightarrow p=q)$.

This concept will also be a weaker version of cancellative semigroup. (I think)

Is there such a concept being used anywhere? Or if not, is there any reason why not (such as having no interesting property, etc.).

Comment: Eventually-regular semigroups are semigroups such that: $\forall x\in S$ there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^k$ has an inverse. In particular, every finite semigroup is eventually-regular.

You could try searching for these. They seem to also be called k-regular semigroups. You may also try searching for "eventually-inverse semigroups".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your definition, a semigroup is weakly inverse if each of its elements has *at most one inverse*. Now, an element has *at least one inverse* if and only if it is regular.
Thus a semigroup is weakly inverse if and only if every regular element has exactly one inverse.

This class of semigroups has been widely studied, at least in the finite case, under the name of *block groups*, because of the very peculiar structure of their regular $\cal D$-classes, represented in the picture below, where $G$ is a maximal group of the $\cal D$-class and a star indicates the presence of an idempotent in the corresponding $\cal H$-class:

$\hskip 100pt$[image]

Block-groups admit several characterizations in terms of [Green relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations).

**Theorem**. Let M be a finite monoid. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. M is a block group;
2. for every regular $\cal D$-class $D$ of $M$, $D^0$ is a [Brandt semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandt_semigroup);
3. for all idempotent $e, f$ of $M$, $e \mathrel{\cal R} f$ implies $e=f$ and $e \mathrel{\cal L} f$ implies $e=f$;
4. for all idempotent $e, f$ of $M$, $efe=e$ implies $ef = e = fe$;
5. the submonoid generated by the idempotents of $M$ is $\cal J$-trivial.

Finite block-trivial monoids are closed under taking submonoids, morphic images (i.e. quotient monoids) and finite direct products
and hence form a [variety of finite monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_of_finite_semigroups).

If $G$ is a group, then ${\cal P}(G)$, the monoid of subsets of $G$, under the operation defined by
$$XY = \{xy \mid x \in X, y \in Y\}$$
is a block-group.
A (difficult) theorem states that the variety of finite monoids **PG** generated by the monoids of the form ${\cal P}(G)$, where $G$ is a group, is equal to the variety **BG** of all finite block-groups. See [1] for a survey and further results.

[1] J.-É. Pin, [**PG** = **BG**, a success story](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/PDF/BGPG.pdf), in NATO Advanced Study Institute, Semigroups, Formal Languages and Groups, J. Fountain (ed.), Kluwer academic publishers (1995) 33-47.

Comment: Looks great. Will take a closer look. Thanks. (ps. thanks for editing my question; it reads more fluent now.)

Comment: It seems that it will take me more than a couple of hours to learn all the relevant concepts & theorems in the semigroup theory to fully understand your comments. For now, I hope I've got a sense about statements 3 and 4 in the theorem above, regarding idempotents. Skipping those I have yet to understand, I tried to follow the example of block-group. Did you actually mean $G$ as opposed to $M$ in the sentence "If $G$ is a group, then ..., the monoid of subsets of $M$?" Or it's actually not a typo, but just I missed the connection between $G$ and $M$?

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing out the typo. Edited now